# How can I make my HTML webpage that has HTML5 video to share the link to Facebook in order to play inline?

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook-graph-api, html5-video

I have an HTML webpage that has HTML5 video. I have included all the necessary meta tags that are following:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.trending-videos.epizy.com/myvideo.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.trending-videos.epizy.com/myvideo.mp4" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type"       content="video/mp4" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width"      content="500" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height"     content="280" />
```

My full HTML code of the page is following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video Title</title>
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://picsum.photos/200" />
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.trending-videos.epizy.com/myvideo.mp4" />
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.trending-videos.epizy.com/myvideo.mp4" /> 
        <meta property="og:video:type"       content="video/mp4" /> 
        <meta property="og:video:width"      content="500" /> 
        <meta property="og:video:height"     content="280" />
    </head>
<body>
     
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="https://www.trending-videos.epizy.com/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I have searched on stackoverflow and applied many solutions but none of them worked. Some of them are following:

[Share html5 video on website to facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344960/share-html5-video-on-website-to-facebook)

[Embedding video player html5 iframe in facebook share like YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815838/embedding-video-player-html5-iframe-in-facebook-share-like-youtube)[Embed html5 video player in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503108/embed-html5-video-player-in-facebook)

[Make og:video play inline whatsapp and facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423319/make-ogvideo-play-inline-whatsapp-and-facebook)

And many more but none of them worked for me. I can see the og:image when I debug my link at [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

I just want to make my webpage to be shareable on facebook. And when I share the link to facebook, this video on my webpage should play in Facebook along with the thumbnail of the video. I don't want to show image thumbnail instead of the video thumbnail.

NOTE: I got Free SSL from zeroSSL. Now getting this message in Facebook debugger

> Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.

Comment: Facebook does not play external videos inside the news feed any more, even if you provide the correct tags. They will only link to the external page.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you tell me if I can make a video thumbnail instead of Image thumbnail?

Comment: You can use `og:image` to specify which image it will show. Not sure what the difference between a "video thumbnail" and an "image thumbnail" is supposed to be, both would be images, no?

Comment: @CBroe, By video thumbnail I mean that the link should get first frame of video along with play icon. So when a user click on play icon on Facebook, it then redirect to my webpage. Hope you got my point of video thumbnail

Comment: You will have to create one from your video's first frame yourself then, and put a fake "play" button on it.

Comment: Ok I got your idea. Thanks.